# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net, iis

i have window 8 server installed and on deploying my asp.net application iam getting this error
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Most likely causes:
•It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all content.
•The feature you are trying to use may not be installed.
•The appropriate MIME map is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.)
•If ASP.NET is not installed.

Comment: What type of page are you trying to serve? ie. What is the extension?

Comment: asp.net page with aspx extension

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have not installed [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28VS.80%29.aspx)

This will register your .NET framework for you and should solve the problem.